# How many files does FileUploader accept when multi-select is enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am getting the following error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Additional information: Maximum request length exceeded.

when I try to upload 250 jpegs which are 98.kb in size so roughly a total of 31 mb. Now 
I know that fileuploader doesn't allow a file over 4mb by default does this mean that each single file must be less than 4mb or that each single upload attempt total size must be less than 4mb?

I googled around for a solution and tried the following in my web config

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

but I still got the same error !??

here is my code:

```
public partial class ReUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session.Remove("paths");
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            Session.Add("paths",uploads);

        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            try
            {
                // Get the HttpFileCollection
                HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                        string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Uploaded") + "\\" + fn;
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(fn + " succsessfully uploaded");
                        hpf.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle your exception here
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }  
                    else if(ListBox1.Items.Count != 0)
             {
                 ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                 HttpFileCollection hfc = (HttpFileCollection)Session["paths"];

                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                        string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Uploaded") + "\\" + fn;
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(fn + " succsessfully uploaded");
                        hpf.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    }
                 }

             }
                    else
             {

                 Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
             }


    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {

                // Get the HttpFileCollection
                HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

                Session["paths"] = hfc;
                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(hpf.FileName);
                    }
                }
                //ViewState["count"] = ListBox1.Items.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle your exception here
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
        }
    }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting goes in your web.config file. It affects the entire application, though... I don't think you can set it per page.File uploader at time accept only one file. For [asynchronous file upload use Ajax control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

"xxx" is in KB. The default is 4096 (= 4 MB).

Comment: OK i did as you suggested and I still get the same error... It works fine when I try to upload lets say 10 or 15 or 20 files but when I try 250 I get this error so I want to know what is the default limit of the number of files you can upload at once using the asp.net file-Uploader ? the only way I can figure this out right now is through trial and error and guess work and would like  to avoid that plus I would like to set the limit too?

Comment: Fabio Delarias: It's depends on your server memory. You need to dispose your File object.Because IO is UN-managed for CLR,also you need to manage your session. Put your code here.

Comment: Ok I have included my code... is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Saroop..I have two buttons one is an upload button and the other is a preview button which takes the selected items in the file uploader and lists them in a listbox and when the user is satisfied with their selection they click upload which takes the files  in the file-uploader or listbox

Comment: @FabioDelarias:Dear Problem with not your file uploader. You try to store your files in session. So when you try to saved files into session above the Machine memory it's throw exception.Because InProc mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). So now you need to manage your session.

Comment: @FabioDelarias:I hope these will help you to solve your issue.